# Is it important for an International Student to arrive in the airport near to his university?

Tags: uk, international-travel, study

Would arriving in an airport that is not near to my University cause any problems at airport?I am getting a Cheap Flight this way.

Comment: Did you add in the cost of ground transport?

Comment: Most people don't choose their connections and gateways solely on proximity; immigration officials understand this. Whether your arrival is suspicious or not would likely be up to the judgment of the immigration officer, and so your question is probably unanswerable here. I'll say this: if you're headed for St. Andrew's, sure, it's reasonable to fly into Glasgow or even London instead of Dundee or Edinburgh. But if you're arriving in the UK on a flight to Belfast, I'd expect some thorough questioning.

Comment: I did add ground transport cost.I am thinking about arriving at Edinburgh instead of Manchester.

Comment: Price isn't everything. You haven't said where you're university is, but assuming it's Manchester, you need to consider the availability of  transport from Edinburgh. If your flight arrives late there might not be a train that day so you'd need an overnight stay. Services can be limited with COVID19 restrictions, so you might not get a seat on the train you want. If your flight is delayed what happens if you miss your booked train? I'm not saying  you shouldn't pick the cheapest flight, but just be aware of the possible issues with onward travel.

Comment: If you're proposing to do this journal shortly then you may also need to consider that Scotland has different criteria on if you need to self isolate then England. Although I don't know if you'd be allowed to travel from Scotland to England if required to self isolate in Scotland (but not England)

Answer (score 5):

When I started studying at a university in Birmingham, I flew from Toronto to Edinburgh because the flight + train was significantly cheaper than flying into other closer airports. They asked me which school I was studying at, and it didn't seem to faze them that it was 300 miles away.

---

As an aside, I'm not even sure they would know which university one is studying at without asking or doing some database querying. The UK Entry Clearance in my passport doesn't have the institution's name on it, nor does the confirmation page from the Home Office (remember to bring this!), nor does my BRP. They all bear an alphanumeric code that's associated with my CAS number (Confirmation of Acceptance of Studies), but I'm not sure whether their systems immediately indicate "studying at University of X".

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.

If they ask you about it, just tell them it's cheaper (including ground transport) from when you are flying from.

Have with you all necessary documents, visa, ...  including university admissions documents.

Answer (score 0):

Because you clear immigration at your first landing in the US it is absolutely normal that people immigrate at an airport nowhere near their final destination. They will probably ask you what your final destination is but as long as you know how you are getting there it will be no problem.